# (0 , _helperModuleTransforms.getModuleName) is not a function - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

The Application was working before I ran `pod update` inside the `ios` folder. After that, I started to get this error.

```
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.1",
```

> bundling failed: index.js:
>   /Users/yamankatby/Documents/Projects/plannerscheduler-mobile/index.js:
>   (0 , _helperModuleTransforms.getModuleName) is not a function

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I fixed this issue by removing my node_modules folder and then npm install again.
Hope it will help you.

Comment: This works - just make sure your package.json file is in tact and houses all of the most recent libraries.

Comment: See also: Use Yarn.